# Sqlite and Window Already Focused

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I keep getting this:

> 07-02 14:50:23.597: WARN/InputManagerService(1496): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46609b50

this is the code that is executed right before hand:

```
db.delete(clicked);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Deleted Row: " + clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Log.i("ContextMenu", "[MainAct.Class] Clicked DELETE. Deleting: " + clicked);
update();
return true;

public void delete(int row){
    open();
    this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id = " + row, null);
}

public void open(){
    if(!db.isOpen()){
        SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

I have been trying to fix this for a few days now.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning has nothing to do with the code you have listed. It has to do with the soft keyboard. It is a warning, not an error, so unless you are experiencing more symptoms than this message appearing, just ignore it.

Comment: @Brandon: Again, unless you are experiencing some other symptoms, there is nothing wrong, with your code or anything else. Android spits out warnings for many things that are benign.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I meant that it is not deleting/editing because my code is wrong.

Thanks :)